# Error:Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'jailBrokenViewController''

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am working on an app. I try using **Storyboard ID**, to move from one ViewController to other ViewController. I used following code, after setting storyboard ID (Screenshot attached),

```
jailBrokenViewController *jailBrokenViewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"jailBrokenViewController"];
[self presentViewController:jailBrokenViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Screenshot of storyboard:[StoryBoard ID Clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kCFp.png)

I am getting error:

> 2017-01-24 15:02:07.639 demoObjC[1109:300901]  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'jailBrokenViewController''

XCode Version I am using is 8.2.1.

Comment: Probably, you have added Space as prefix or as prefix of storyboard ID in storyboard or in code.. So, please check for spaces if by mistake added

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if my answer solves your error :) Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing like this to avoid errors:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

jailBrokenViewController *jailBrokenViewController=[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"jailBrokenViewController"];
[self presentViewController:jailBrokenViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Note:
You change the "Main" to your correct storyboard name.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have set `Storyboard ID` in storyboard

[image]